# How to init a final variable in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

We have a service that calls other services to do data integrations. We need to initialize clients to call those external services. For separation of concerns, those clients need to be in a separate sub-module `x`. During the initialization, we are getting an `uninitialized variable` error.

How do we resolve this error and what is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

These are two approaches to handle the requirement.

1. Declare your variables in the module-level and init them inside the module init function, or
2. Declare your variables as service-level variables and init them inside the service init function.

In order to fix the mentioned issues we have to initialize the variable in the module `init` function.

```
int i;

function init() {
    i = 2;
}
```